# How to load and use one more than .class file?

Tags: java

I have a folder in this folder I have 4 .class file  .I want load this files in my main program and call the methods  .for one .class file I do like so:

```
File file = new File("/home/saeed/NetBeansProjects/java-test/build/classes");

URI uri = file.toURI();
URL[] urls = new URL[]{uri.toURL()};

ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);

Class clazz = classLoader.loadClass("com.test.NewClass");
```

And for invoke the method I do like so:

```
Object obj = clazz.newInstance();

System.out.println(""+obj.getClass().
        getMethod("echo",String.class).invoke(obj, "Saeed"));
```

Now I have one more than .class in the folder  .How can I load and invoke their methods?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Um...do the same thing three more times? Or better yet, put that directory in your classpath and use them normally? What's the question here exactly?

Comment: How to load 4 .class file from a folder?

Comment: That question doesn't make any sense. What are you actually trying to do? If you're just trying to use class files in the normal way, you don't use a classloader directly at all. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: @marzie, we do not understand why you use reflection to load these classes? why not put the folder in classpath? and if you insist on using reflection, the obvious answer is to copy-paste `loadClass` with `clazz1` `clazz2` etc

Comment: I insist on using reflection  .I know how to load one .class file but in my folder there is 4 .class file  .How do I load all of them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PathMatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html), here is an example:

```
Path startDir = Paths.get("C:\\home");

String pattern = "*.class";

FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
final PathMatcher matcher = fs.getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);

FileVisitor<Path> matcherVisitor = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attribs) {
        Path name = file.getFileName();
        if (matcher.matches(name)) {
            // Found a .class file 
            System.out.print(String.format("Found matched file: '%s'.%n", file));
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
};
```